# VS, quick way to deploy c# console application across several Windows servers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment

We are developing application(console) which is deployed on seven windows servers. It is very time consuming to update such app in every server when new version is released. Maybe someone could suggest any solution how to make deployment of such app as quick as possible?

I see only one solution is to deploy app on shared folder and run app from it on all servers. Not sure is this good idea.

Comment: You can do that manually or with VS tool. I'd recomend second one because writing it by your own is much more complicated. As far as I remember VS tool updater have autoupdate option at startup but need user confirmation before it starts so it might not be the best scenario for servers, but if it seems OK for you I can provide you step by step solution, it's just few clicks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would post this as a comment but don't have enough rep, perhaps someone can add a comment to this effect and I'll delete this answer.

Can you clarify whether the update/deployment is a simple case of copying files, or whether an executable needs to be run?

Either way you have two main strategies:

Push - where you update the servers from one central location.

Pull - where each deployment location checks the central location to see if there is a new version each time it is run, and if so, it runs an update before re-launching itself.

If its a constantly on service, then you're better wish Push, else I would advise Pull as its cleaner. I have had success using Pull method with the help of batch files to overcome the chicken and egg problem of a updating a compiled app's own files, but I'm sure there are more elegant solutions...

Comment: I see you edited your question to add: "I see only one solution is to deploy app on shared folder and run app from it on all servers. Not sure is this good idea." which indicates you don't need to actually install it on each server. I think that if you can run it from a central apps folder that would be better. Otherwise replicating a file directory is a straightforward solution using either push or pull...

Comment: I decided to develop my own simple Pull type update. The program itself check version number and verify that number with update on shared folder, if new versions exists I just copy all files from shared folder to Prod server.

Answer (score 0):

With [XCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY)

I believe you can achieve that by creating a batch script that runs after rebuild your solution. Within this .bat script you do XCOPY to the 7 servers.

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY

In computing, Xcopy is a command used on PC DOS, MS-DOS, OS/2, Microsoft Windows, and related operating systems for **copying multiple files or entire directory trees from one directory to another and for copying files across a network.** Xcopy stands for extended copy,[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY) and was created as a more functional file copying utility than the copy command found in these operating systems.